# Spectrogram Analysis

Tags: matlab, spectrogram

I have four .wav files and each contain bird chirps.  Given an input .wav file, I need to find out which bird it is.

I have some basic understanding of signal processing. I have used spectrogram to analyze my audio files and now I don't know how to make the frequency spectrum comparison to find out the solution.

Can someone please let me know the process with which I could find out the frequency of sound, bird chirps in my case, programmatically from the spectrogram? I am just a beginner, so I apologize if I said something which wasn't clear

Comment: You don't want to just find the "frequency of sound", as you say.  You want to find the *shape* of the sound in the spectrogram.  Chirps consist of many frequencies.  Are you able to look at the spectrogram as an image and see these shapes?

Comment: Do you know which bird's song is recorded in each file? Can you hear the differences between them? Even being able to distinguish between the four files you have does not imply that anything you generate will be able to reliably distinguish other birds' songs.

Comment: @Peter , Yes I know the which file has which bird recorded in it .. You can make out the difference between each of them..

Comment: Thanx for all your input guys , I could manage it at the end .. :)

Comment: @Phonon: Why not to make this question protected?

Answer (score 5):

Please check [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8220/performing-classification-based-on-fft-results), which describes a few approaches to the same problem. Given that bird song is a monophonic signal (only one fundamental frequency at any point in time - as opposed to polyphonic) - and given that the timbre is irrelevant, the most interesting feature to extract for this classification task is a pitch contour.